# Convert non-missing date to missing in R

Tags: r, dplyr, sqldf

I have a data frame and I want to replace a date column of only the first row of each ID to missing based on a condition.

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- read.table("
id date1      var
1  01/02/1992  2
1  02/03/1992  1
1  01/03/1992  2
2  06/05/1992  1
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

date1 <- as.Date(date1)
table1 <- data.frame(id,date1,var)
```

This seems like a simple task and I have tried several codes and none of them is working.  I am new to R so please excuse my pedestrian question.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  I made the correction in my post.

Comment: thanks, based on the format of 'date1', the `as.Date` would need a `format` argument.  Also, I believe you want the first value of 'date1' to be NA for each 'id'.  Please check whether you want the solution in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to replace the first value of Date to NA, then do a group by 'id' and use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
table1 <- table1 %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(date1 = replace(date1, 1, NA))
```

---

If 'date1' is not ordered

```
table1 %>%
    arrange(id, as.Date(date1, '%d/%m/%Y')) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(date1 = replace(date1, 1, NA))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(table1)[, date1 := replace(date1, 1, NA), id]
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun!  Could you give me the solution in data.table as well?  I have been suggested to learn data.table so that's what I am using.

Comment: If I were to replace all but first row of each ID, how would the code change?

Comment: @Pam We could change the `replace` to `replace(date1, -1, NA)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `duplicated` :

```
table1$date1[!duplicated(table1$id)] <- NA
table1

#  id      date1 var
#1  1       <NA>   2
#2  1 02/03/1992   1
#3  1 01/03/1992   2
#4  2       <NA>   1
```